# Do you filter the input to all your functions in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

One thing that always perplexes me about writing my Elixir functions is if I should filter or `normalize` my functions. The reason behind this is because Elixir tends to treat `"input"` and `'input'` differently one being a bitstring and the other being a char list.

Is it better to filter and normalize all input or just let it error out saying that you sent a char list instead of the expected bitstring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Elixir libraries only handle bitstrings (double quoted) and require you to convert charlists (single quoted) manually before using the library.

However, it entirely depends on your use case. For example, if I'd write a library that takes as input the output of another erlang library, it would be inconvenient if you have to convert the charlist every time you use the library. IMHO this would just be bad API design. Still, I think you shouldn't handle charlists as long as you don't explicitly need them. Bitstrings are the standard way in Elixir to handle strings, no need to add all the conversion clutter to every method.

Lastly, it is indeed a problem that the error message can be very cryptic and somerimes comes from deep down inside a library. This is a general disadvantage of dynamically typed languages. I still wouldn't handle the case explicitly, because it's just not part of the API.